# Getting a sample Device token

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to get device token from my iphone. After reading the post in stackoverflow, I have done this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert ];
}
  (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{
    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: %@", deviceToken);
}
```

I have put a breakpoint in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken, but it is not stopping there. How do I ensure that it gets called?

Sorry for the noob question.. Need some guidance on this...

Comment: find the full tutorial - http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Comment: Eanble push notification for your app(means add notification service to your provisioning profile).Then try again.

Answer (score 1):

There may be any reason for this.

Either you have done something wrong while generating .cer file or you have not installed new provisioning in XCode by deleting old provisioning after configuring your app for PUSH NOTIFICATION SERVICES.

So check once again in provisioning portal while configuring your app for apple push notification services. And download .cer file again. 
Then generate .pem file(It contains private key) from .cer file.
Then download new provisioning profile again and then remove old provisioning from XCode and install new provisioning.

Then use this :

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Push Notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)_deviceToken {
    // Get a hex string from the device token with no spaces or < >

    NSString *deviceToken = [[NSString alloc] init];

    deviceToken = [[[[_deviceToken description]
                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    NSLog(@"deviceToken = %@",deviceToken);

  }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Shouldn't rely on description - it's not guaranteed to remain the same. Use this instead: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
                          ntohl(tokenBytes[0]), ntohl(tokenBytes[1]), ntohl(tokenBytes[2]),
                          ntohl(tokenBytes[3]), ntohl(tokenBytes[4]), ntohl(tokenBytes[5]),
                          ntohl(tokenBytes[6]), ntohl(tokenBytes[7])]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new provisioning profile for your application and sign you application with the same. And you have to run the application in the device for getting the device token. If you are running application in simulator it will return error.

Go through the tutorial given

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html